# Any difference in meaning between: "I don't get weighed." AND "I don't weigh myself."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language

1- **"I don't weigh myself."**

2- **"I don't get weighed."**

I heard the first one being used. And I just googled the second one, because it is grammatically closer to my mother tongue (passive voice). And I got hits from the google but very much less than the first one.

So, I am not sure whether the second one is as idiomatic as the first one?

Comment: They typically mean different things. The second one typically means somebody else (a nurse etc) is doing the weighing/recording the weight; the first means you are doing it yourself. Both are fairly idiomatic; which is more idiomatic I'm unsure.

Comment: I don't know why this question got two downvotes, maybe native speakers know instinctively which one  they would use/say in which specific situation. For example; 2 "When I enter surgery (medical studio) **I'm never weighed** [by my doctor]"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree. It's as if the downvoting thing has got way out of hand.///Look, I just got two downvotes. Unbelievable, isn't it? Talk about sour apples...

Comment: Yunus, for your glossary: it seems we have a hard row to hoe. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MORE context is always better:

1- "I don't weigh myself every week." [step on the scales to find out what I weigh]

2- "I don't get weighed when I go to the physical therapist."

to be weighed=formal [written], informal-get weighed [more spoken]

to be or get weighed means some person is weighing you, like a nurse, for example. *get* here is completely idiomatic but care should be taken with the formality of written text.

Both are completely idiomatic.

- Did your dog get weighed last time you took him to the vet?
- Being weighed by a vet is a common practice in dog/cat care.
  _ Dogs and cats may step on scales but they are not *weighing themselves*.

Of course, the passive is: He is weighed by the nurse at the hospital, when necessary, for his diabetes. But that was not the question.